# In webview, override TouchListener

Tags: android, webview, ontouchlistener

I use webview in android

and need to recognize is it scroll or not

when scroll webview, hide my option tab and stop scrolling, set visible webview.

```
   www.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
            if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP)
            {
                Log.v("motion", "Up");
                option_tab_layout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
            if(event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE){
                Log.v("motion", "move");
                option_tab_layout.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

when return false , ACTION_UP event did not call,
and using return true, webview can not scroll the page

how can i handle it?

Answer (score 1):

I would rather use `onScrollChanged (int l, int t, int oldl, int oldt)`

Doc here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#onScrollChanged(int, int, int, int)